# Dynamic Value in Regexp.replace using javascript

Tags: regex, asp-classic, jscript

I do not know where my head is today, can somebody please explain to me - why I can get the hturl value by the request form and do the replace in the htstring? (I do this and it works - but only replaces one occurance of the (hturl) value.... The problem is that there is about 10 more occurances of the old value that I want to replace:

I am using Regex in conjunction with asp and javascript

```
<% 
htreplace = ""+Request.Form("1")+"";
hturl = Request.Form("thesite");
htstring = htreplace
htstring = htstring.replace(/,;~~~~/ig,';');
htstring = htstring.replace(hturl,'http://www.example.net');
%>
```

If I change the

```
htstring = htstring.replace(hturl,'http://www.example.net');
```

to

```
htstring = htstring.replace(/hturl/ig,'http://www.example.net');
```

or

```
htstring = htstring.replace("/"+hturl+"/"+ig,'http://www.example.net');
```

I cannot get the hturl value dynamically anymore ?

Anybody that can help please do! - I do not know where my head / logic is today! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myregexp = new RegExp(hturl, "ig");

htstring = htstring.replace(myregexp, 'blah');
```

Comment: Thanks Kaze! - Just learned something new and it works 100% zero issues!

Comment: 3 years on, and still very helpful to the world ;-) Thanks so much... was tearing my hair out trying to work through this exact problem